# Extension of the Secretary Problem

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose I have the domain $X = [0,1]$ and $U:X\to\mathbb{R}$ a score function such that $U(X) = (x-1/2)^2$. Let $D$ be a distribution such that $P[X \leq a] = a^2$. 
My algorithm gets theta as a parameter and a sample of m examples from $X$. The algorithm chooses the first x that satisfies $U(x)  \geq \theta$.
I wish to find the value of $\theta$ that maximizes the probability that the $x$ chosen is the maximum among the $m$ examples.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, the distribution of $X$ doesn't really matter in itself. What you care about is the resulting distribution over $U$. Second, the distribution over $U$ doesn't really matter either, as long as it's continuous, since all you care about is the relative order of independent draws from the distribution.

Comment: I've calculated that P[U(x) <= theta] = 2(sqrt(theta)). My problem is that I don't know how to continue from here - how do I calculate whats the theta that maximizes the probability that x is maximum among those that are bigger than theta? After all, I don't know how many x's are larger than theta.

Comment: Please ask questions of this type at https://math.stackexchange.com/ . Since (unlike in the original secretary problem) you have the distribution of $U$, you know where you're at throughout, and the right strategy is to keep going as long as the (conditional) probability that matters will still improve is $>1/2$.